# Can we access database without SQL Server Management Studio in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a database name="records" with the help of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Now my question if I uninstall SSMS then can I still access the database from a C# program? If yes, then then is the process for connectivity still same as given below?

```
SqlConnection cnn ; 
string connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
 cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
```

Comment: SSMS is just another client - uninstalling it will have no affect on accessing the database from other programs.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 3):

Management Studio is just a *GUI client* for interacting with a database. It is separate from the actual database.

In other words: you don't need Management Studio to programmatically access a MS SQL database.

Comment: .... but you **do need** the actual SQL Server **engine** installed, of course ...

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer, yes.

The management tools are an optional extra, all you really need is the database server.